Solving an equation for different values of a parameter
I need to solve the following equation for [Omega] for different values of $tt$ in the range $0=<tt=<2 \pi$, and then plot the largest solution as a function of tt, for a few differnt values of m. The tricky part of it is that I need to first set the value of tt and then solve the equation and plot it.
Could someone help me with this? The equation is
eqw= (9 (12 + 81 m) (m - 2 \[Omega]) Cos[tt]^2 +  m (-12 + 81 m) Sin[tt]^2)/(
     216 (9 (-m + 2 \[Omega]) Cos[tt]^2 + m Sin[tt]^2)) == \[Omega]


ContourPlot[  eqw /. m -> 3 // Evaluate, {tt, 0, 2 π}, {ω, -20, 20},   FrameLabel -> {"tt", "ω"}]

Thanks, but this does not plot the maximum solution. The equation has two solutions @cvgmt

Yes, that is why I does not post it as answer. Maybe  eqw = (9 (12 + 81 m) (m - 2 ω) Cos[tt]^2 +        m (-12 + 81 m) Sin[tt]^2)/(216 (9 (-m + 2 ω) Cos[tt]^2 +          m Sin[tt]^2)) == ω; m = 3; Plot[Max@NSolveValues[eqw, ω], {tt, 0, 2 π},   Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

the solution is wrong. When I set tt=0 and solve the equation I get a solution that does not match yours! @cvgmt

YOU ARE RIGHT, THERE WAS A TYPO


We mention that ContourPlot missing may solutions, it is not suitable for this problem.
Here we only test m=3.

Clear["Global`*"];
eqw = (9 (12 + 81 m) (m - 2 ω) Cos[tt]^2 + 
      m (-12 + 81 m) Sin[tt]^2)/(216 (9 (-m + 2 ω) Cos[tt]^2 + 
        m Sin[tt]^2)) == ω;
m=3;
sol=Solve[Rationalize[eqw, 0], ω, Reals]
FunctionDiscontinuities[#, tt] & /@ (ω /. sol)
Plot[ω /.sol, {tt, 0, 
  2 π}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]




the Max solution.

Clear["Global`*"];
eqw = (9 (12 + 81 m) (m - 2 ω) Cos[tt]^2 + 
      m (-12 + 81 m) Sin[tt]^2)/(216 (9 (-m + 2 ω) Cos[tt]^2 + 
        m Sin[tt]^2)) == ω;
sol = Solve[Rationalize[eqw, 0], ω, Reals];
Plot[Table[Max[ω /. sol], {m, {1, 2, 3}}] // Evaluate, {tt, 0, 
  2 π}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]



I am a bit lost. The discontinuous points are real solutions. Why don't they appear in your graph then?

@Marco  Only two discontinuous points in the range 0<=tt<=2Pi,  Solve[{FunctionDiscontinuities[#, tt] & /@ (ω /. sol) // First,    0 <= tt <= 2 π}, tt]  we get  {{tt -> π/2}, {tt -> (3 π)/2}}

So the discontinuous points appearing at tt=0 and tt=pi in Alex's answer are incorrect?

@Marco  The result by @AlexTrounev is right. There are three discontinuous points . {0, π, 2 π} in the original problem.

One possible solution is
eqw = (9 (12 + 81 m) (m - 2 \[Omega]) Cos[tt]^2 + 
     m (-12 + 81 m) Sin[tt]^2)/(216 (9 (-m + 2 \[Omega]) Cos[tt]^2 + 
       m Sin[tt]^2)) == \[Omega]; 
sols[m1_] := 
 Table[{tt, Max[\[Omega] /. NSolve[eqw /. m -> m1, \[Omega]]]}, {tt, 
   0, 2 Pi,  Pi/50}];

ListPlot[Table[sols[m], {m, 1, 3}], 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"m = ", m}], {m, 1, 3}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"tt", "\[Omega]"}]



Is it possible to interpolate these data points so that the graph shows lines instead of dots?

@Marco Try option Joined->Trueinside ListPlot

Is this the largest solution?

Yes, this is maximal solution since we used Max[] to select solution in every point.

@Marco For my opinion dots are better than line, since we can see unique solutions in the bottom part.

Your solution does not match with that of cvgmt, in particular at tt=0,pi,2pi

Do you mean that cvgmt solution does not much my solution at tt=0,pi,2pi? :) Maybe you know why? Simply check Table[{tt,    Max[\[Omega] /. Solve[eqw /. m -> 3, \[Omega]]]}, {tt, {0, Pi,     2 Pi}}] and see out {{0, -(85/72)}, {\[Pi], -(85/72)}, {2 \[Pi], -(85/72)}}. These are unique solutions that have been dropped by cvgmt. You can use these solutions or drop them as well :)

@Marco I added step Pi/50 to see unique solutions for m=1 as well.

ContourPlotworks too and confirms @AlexTrounev's result
ContourPlot[
Evaluate@Table[ eqw , { m, 1, 3 }], {tt, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Omega], 0,Pi}, FrameLabel -> {"tt", "\[Omega]"}  ]



It is a bit different from Alex solution as there is a void in the graph

Please test {ω, -10, 10}, We need to plot the Max of curves.

@Marco Try option PlotPointsinside ContourPlot!

@cvgmt ContourPlot shows the correct solution for case {ω, -10, 10} I think. Change Max to Minin AlexTrounev's answer to confirm.

@UlrichNeumann the OP is want to plot the largest solution instead of the all the solution.

@cvgmt May answer shows the same curves ( m=1,2,3) as Alex's answer!

ContourPlot missing many solutions. For example check tt near  3.

@cvgmt ContourPlot[  Evaluate@Table[eqw, {m, {3}}], {tt, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Omega], -Pi, Pi},   FrameLabel -> {"tt", "\[Omega]"}]  shows correct solution I think. Especially at t=0,Pi/2,Pi,3Pi/2,2Pi it shows that there exists only one solution!

ContourPlot is wrong. For example, ContourPlot missing the point when Pi-1/4<=tt<=Pi+1/4. ContourPlot[  Evaluate@   Table[eqw, {m, {3}}], {tt, π - 1/4, π + 1/4}, {ω, 0,    Pi}, FrameLabel -> {"tt", "ω"}]

@cvgmt Increase PlotPoints and ContourPlot shows a little bit more. ContourPlot "isn't wrong" , only incomplete. it only shows contours where eqw changes sign.

Whatever you change PlotPoints, the ContourPlot still missing the points.
